# C parse json objects with same names

Tags: c, json, libjson

I parse json in C, by "json-c/json.h".

I have structure: `section: [ {item: {...}, item: {...}, ..., item: {...}} ]`

I can get 1 item by:

```
struct json_object item = json_object_object_get(section, "item");
```

How I can get count of items, and parse all items?

Comment: I have big `typedef struct` for storage each item.
And me need allocated array of items, before parse them.

Comment: Is that really your correct string? The JSON array seems a bit weird. I would expect something more like `section: [{item: {...}}, {item: {...}},... {item: {...}}]`

Comment: I know about, what must seems json. It's simply example for what i mean, not for discussion about example.